# How can I create a map-based app for my town?

Tags: ruby, geolocation, gis, geocoding

I want to create a map-based web app for my town. It's small, like only 5 x 5 miles, so I'd like to download a map image or tiled image set to use for the site.

For such a small area I think I could just cache the map image or images. Then I wouldn't need to depend on Google or another map service, which seems like overkill for my tiny area. I want to map events by street address, so I would need to plot addresses on the map images.

Can I download a local map like this somewhere? How can I build this app? I spent about a day reading about map stuff, like what Everyblock did and OpenStreetMap, but am completely lost because the sites don't really talk about how the tools are used. There has to be a known set of tools I can use to build this! If somebody could tell me what map tools I should be looking at that would help a lot. Thx!

Comment: Actually, relying on a Google map or other similar map API is probably the best way to go here.  You would be surprised at the level of detail that is present in even the smallest of maps.

Comment: Thanks, I may have to. Bing Maps is doing a better job of plotting my locations (which can be funky), so I may use that instead of Google. But even that doesn't seem clear, using Ruby for example. Also the streets in my town are stable so I thought I could build a cache of my maps and data over time so I wouldn't have to worry about throttling and other dependency problems.

Comment: I think openstreetmap is the way to go. It has tons of apis and services for such projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [San Francisco Neighborhood Project](http://hood.theory.org/)... these guys parse the neighborhood names mentioned in craigslist, geolocate the associated address, then color-code the map based on the frequency of name occurrences.  The [python source](https://bitbucket.org/glyphobet/neighborhood/src) - with data classification, warehousing, geolocation and graphing - if that helps...

Comment: Thanks. They mention TIGER which I read about, but got confused. I did get a TIGER download with a bunch of stuff like shapefiles (more confusion). They say their map file came from TIGER, but I can't find where TIGER has maps available (the link on their site to census.gov says it was retired in May 2010). Getting a map is one of the things I need to do if I'm not going to use a mapping service. :)

Comment: TIGER is a bunch of data that helps classify geography by demographic divisions... there is a [python script](http://beej.us/btiger/) available to parse the format directly... or you can download in SQL format from [Open PHI.com](http://www.openphi.com/opencensusgeocoding.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will check those out. See this from their homepage? "The map is from the TIGER/Line US Census data." That's what I mean about getting a map like that (is there enough data to generate a map or where did they get it?).

Comment: @mapapp You can use google maps for free as long as you are not charging for your application... otherwise the maps license is probably out of your budget (on the order of $10k/year).  I display data as [KML on google maps](http://www.ninemoreminutes.com/2009/12/google-maps-with-python-and-kml/), since most of what I do is data-mining for my own research.  The nice thing about KML is you use google's rendering engine for the map, zooming, and point placement... you just supply the lat/long/description on the map

Comment: @mapapp I'm not sure how you will use the data, or how granular the data is for your town... it's possible it has enough detail, but it's probably worth your time to take a look

Comment: The only problem with Google is it isn't interpreting my addresses, sometimes intersections, as good as Bing, so I might use that instead. But it would be nice to have everything under my control so I could do more parsing and customizing of my specific data and its display. KML looks like what I'd want for Google Maps because I need to display multiple locations.

Comment: The TIGER stuff looks good but may be too much for me to figure out for this personal project. I couldn't find a good starting point.

Comment: @mapapp, geocoding is orthogonal to display... you can use bing for lat/long resolution and google to present the points... Lat / Long inputs are fine for KML plots

Comment: That's a good point. Too bad geocoder, the Ruby library I was going to use, uses either Google or Yahoo, so I'll need to figure out how to use Bing. This mapping stuff seems complicated!

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). You can use the data in various ways (make a "slippy map" like Google maps uses, create fixed map images, render your own map images from their raw data...).

To be more specific, you'd need to explain in more detail what you need.

If you want to plot stuff by street address, you'll need address information in addition to images. The simplest option is probably to use existing web services, such as [Nominatim](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/)
(which offers an API via HTTP), or set up your own server using theses services.

Of course, you could also download the raw data and set up everything from scratch, possibly building on existing libraries. But that really depends on what exactly you need...

Comment: Thanks, any pointers for the last part? I haven't found a good starting point for my reading, the sites sort of assume you already know what everything is.

Comment: @mapapp410: Hard to say, depends on what you need. Basically you need to get the raw data (download as XML via the XAPI http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Xapi ), then render it somehow. There are various renderers available, or make your own: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering . Finally, for concrete help browse (and post) on the specific forum: http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: Thank you. I think that's what I was missing, a simple description of how it works and where to start. This was a very helpful comment but I don't seem to have up-vote power for either the comment or your answer.